# What is the "relationships" tag for?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The tag wiki for [relationships](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) says, "Relationship is a module used for relating entities."  However, the [Relationship](http://drupal.org/project/relationship) module has been abandoned.  While there is a new [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module for D7, most of the tags in this section appear to be about Relationships in Views.

Is it possible to rename tags?  I would propose a separate tag for the Relations module and a views-relationships tag (similar to the existing [views-filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-filter), [views-handler](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-handler)) so that there is less ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed [relationships](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) from the questions where the tag was referring to a generic relationship, and renamed it [views-relationships](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-relationships). There could still be some questions using [views-relationships](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-relationships) that should not be using it because the question is not about a view relationship.

I also edited the tag wiki for that tag to the following text:

> This tag is for questions about relationships used with the Views module.

The tag wiki needs to be improved.

There is already [relation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relation), which is already used for the Relation module.